# How to render a single object to png with camera and lights?

Tags: rendering, objects, render-layers

I would like to render this object in png and not all the objects.

I would like to do it separately, while keeping the camera, light etc..

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: enable Render > Film > Transparent?

Comment: no my question is, how to export a single object in png format and not all the objects of the image, when I press f12 it gives me all the objects

Comment: Deselect all the objects you don't want to render (uncheck camera icon) in the Outliner?

Comment: Oh damn that's not true! Thank you I had stopped blender for 2 weeks and there I fell again facing this problem, Thank you